# regarding repsone.redirect in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
    Dim Uname As String
    Dim pwd As String
    Dim pName As String
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Uname = Login1.UserName

    pwd = Login1.Password
    pName = ""
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionASPX").ConnectionString

    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Conn.Open()


    Dim sqlUserName As String
    sqlUserName = "SELECT UserName,Password FROM Customer"
    sqlUserName &= " WHERE (UserName = @Uname"
    sqlUserName &= " AND Password = @Pwd)"

    Dim com As New SqlCommand(sqlUserName, Conn)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", Uname)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", pwd)


    reader = com.ExecuteReader()
    If (reader.Read()) Then

        Me.Response.Redirect("Faq.aspx")
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid UserName-password")


    End If
    reader.Close()
    Conn.Close()

    'If CurrentName <> "" Then
    '    Session("UserAuthentication") = Uname

    '    Response.Redirect("Faq.aspx")
    'Else
    '    Session("UserAuthentication") = ""
    'End If


End Sub
```

the code kis working without any errors . It is not redirecting to another page.

Comment: U sure there is something to read?

Comment: @Rune I think they just want to show an example of good, clean, working code for us all to enjoy.

Comment: it is not redirecting to the page i have mentioned in the code.

Comment: it displays the same login page again

Comment: So it just refreshes the page?

Comment: yess it is just refreshing neeed help

Comment: i would not recommend performing redirect in that place because reader and connection will remain open. Instead implement a boolean variable to set its value in If Else condition and based on it perform redirect AFTER closing both reader and connection

Comment: Are you sure that that Login1_Authenticate is even called? Could Faq.aspx redirect back to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint (press F9) on the line `If (reader.Read()) Then` and then press F5 to run the app in debug mode and step through that line to see if it is skipping your Response.Redirect call.  If it is, you will have to figure out why the Read() method is returning false.